# Put request in strapi

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, strapi

I have a table of users, a user has favorite items, one user can have many items. In the admin panel, I can freely add/remove items, but how can I do this in the form of a request?

I am interested in the mechanism itself, the process of adding and removing elements. I have the necessary ID to delete and add. How to write correctly?

I need a PUT request

```js
async updateFavorites(id, status) {
    let {
        data,
        error
    } = await useFetch(
        `${useRuntimeConfig().env.STRAPI_URL}/api/users/${this.user.id}`, {
            method: "PUT",
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${this.jwt}`,
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: {

            }
        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a new element to the array, I just added a new id to the array, `strapi` picked up the id itself and found a match. If there is a relationship with another element in the table, it is enough to add an id.

```js
 
 this.user.Favorites.push(id);
        let { data, error } = await useFetch(
          `${useRuntimeConfig().public.strapi.url}/api/users/${this.user.id}`,
          {
            method: "PUT",
            headers: {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${cookie.value}`,
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: {
              Favorites: this.user.Favorites,
            },
          }
        );
```